# how to change the style attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   .containerTitle {
     background-color:silver;
     text-align:center;
     font-family:'Segoe UI';
     font-size:18px;
     font-weight:bold;
     height:30px;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"/>
</body>
</html>
```

how to change the background-color in containerTitle style using jquery..

Comment: Where is `.containerTitle` class in your html?

Comment: one more thing, <div id="a"/> should be <div id="a"></div>

Comment: toggle a class and write a rule that includes both classes and set the properties you want in the stylesheet. Is easiest to undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go: `$(".containerTitle").css("background-color","red");`

usage example:

```js
// wait until the DOM tree is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
  // click event handler on <a> tags
  $("a").click(function() {
    // change the color on click
    $(".containerTitle").css("background-color","red");
  });
});
```

```css
.containerTitle {
  background: black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerTitle"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" >change color</a>
```

Comment: Hernandez  in your sample u are used class in div... without assigning class how we can achieve?

Comment: well you need an identifier, because if not it will be harder to change just that element. Because you can use `$("div").css("background-color","red");` but that  will change the background of every `div` on your page. Another thing that you can do: `$("#idOfParent div").css("background-color","red");` that will change the background on every `div` inside of your element `<x id="idOfParent">`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".containerTitle").css(
    "background","#dedede"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".containerTitle ").css("background-color","silver");
    });
    </script>
```

and also you should js library in your head section of your code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

and this `<div id="a"/>` should be like this, `<div id="a" ></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to change the style attribute dynamically.

```
$('.containerTitle').css({'background':'red'})
```